# Ограничение ввода в text field по маске (JavaFx 8)

Tags: java, javafx

Необходимо ограничить ввод в текстовое поле по маске, как показано на картинке. К примеру, для гарантированного ввода целых чисел для даты или времени (час:минуты).

[image]

Использую JavaFx 8.
Гуглил в поисках решения - ничего не помогло. Будто javafx 8 и не позволяет такое провернуть. Help!

Answer (score 1):

Для ввода даты в JavaFX есть специальный компонент - `DatePicker`

Answer (score 0):

Не пробовали ли вешать листенер на textField и если текущий текст неудовлетворяет регулярке, то дизайблить кнопку/запрещать двигаться дальше?